# DSpace 6.2 Document Item View Customization

Tags: css, sass, dspace

I am trying to customize the View Item tab on my repository and add styling.
The default style looks like this.
[image]

To one sort of like this one.

[image: Customized]

I've tried modifying the *_item-lists.scss* file under `/[source]/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/` but there's no change.

Answer (score 0):

The file responsible for these changes is the *item-view.xsl* file found in `[source]/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/`